Large Hexadecimal (18 characters) to decimal conversions Incorrect in C program
I am trying to make a small C program to convert 18 character hexadecimal numbers (example: ec6260d8b431e420d6) to decimal. However every time I check the code I have with a online converter it's always wrong.  I've read that my variable type might not be large enough for the numbers I'm attempting to convert, and to use unsigned variables when not using negative numbers.  When I look at the code I am using I don't know where to change the aforementioned possible solutions.  Here is the code I'm using:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char hex[100];
    printf("Enter a hexadecimal number: ");
    scanf("%s", hex);
    long decimal = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (hex[i] != '\0') {
        int digit = hex[i] - '0';
        if (digit >= 10) {
            digit -= 7;
        }
        decimal = decimal * 16 + digit;
        i++;
    }
    printf("The decimal equivalent of %s is %ld.\n", hex, decimal);
    return 0;
}

Any pointers and suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong or not understanding would be greateley appreciated.

This is a 72-bit value. You cannot represent it in a long, or any standard primitive integer type. You need to manually divide out the value (with long division) into a string, or use a large integer library.

18 chars hex is 72 bits. long is probably 64 bits, so it does sound like overflow. Have you tried your code on smaller hex strings ? Depending on your compiler etc, you may have a bigger integer type like __int128

long may only be 32 bits. Unless you have a 16-bit int type, it is a useless type (except if some interface needs it). Use long long or int64_t for 64 bits, but of course, that's not enough.

You compiler might provide a 128 bit integer type. If not, your best bet is some library

If the user enters a lower-case letter as a hexadecimal digit, then subtracting 7 won't be sufficient. This will only work for upper-case hexadecimal digits.

One option is to use a bigint library like GMP or OpenSSL's

There are at least two problems in the OP code:

Decoding of the entered hexadecimal number: the conversion only supports uppercase letters and there is no check that the digits are valid.
The conversion assumes that the entire number fits in a single variable: 18 hexadecimal digits correspond to 72 bits which may or may not be supported by the platform. If it is available, using a 128-bit unsigned integer is the easiest and most efficient option, but it is not portable and does not scale to hexadecimal numbers longer than 32 digits.

The first issue can be addressed by this answer (modified to read one digit at a time and added error handling): Hexadecimal string to byte array in C
The second issue can be addressed by storing the hexadecimal digits in an array and implement the necessary "big int" operation (division by 10 with remainder) as described in this answer (modified to base 16 instead of base 256): how can i in c convert a very big hex number into an array of decimal?
All in all:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Divide 16-base number by 10 and return remainder
unsigned char div10(unsigned char *hex, unsigned size)
{
    unsigned rem = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        unsigned n = rem * 16 + hex[i];
        hex[i] = n / 10;
        rem = n % 10;
    }
    return rem;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char hex[101];
    printf("Enter a hexadecimal number: ");
    scanf("%100s", hex);

    // Decode hexadecimal number
    const char *pos = hex;
    unsigned hex_count = 0;

    unsigned char hex_digits[100];  // Digit values 0-15, most significant first
    while(*pos != 0)
    {
        short unsigned hex;
        if(sscanf(pos, "%1hx", &hex) != 1)
        {
            printf("ERROR: invalid hex digit '%c'\n", *pos);
             // Error: not a valid hex digit
        }
        else
        {
            hex_digits[hex_count++] = hex;
        }
        pos++;
    }

    // Convert hexadecimal to decimal
    unsigned char hex_zero[100] = {0};
    unsigned dec_count = 0;
    unsigned char dec_digits[130];  // Digit values 0-9, most significant first, aligned to end of array
    while(memcmp(hex_digits, hex_zero, hex_count) != 0 && dec_count < sizeof(dec_digits))
    {
        dec_digits[sizeof(dec_digits) - dec_count - 1] = div10(hex_digits, hex_count);
        dec_count++;
    }

    // Display decimal number
    if(memcmp(hex_digits, hex_zero, hex_count) != 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: result buffer too small\n");
    }
    else if(dec_count == 0)
    {
        printf("0\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for(unsigned n = 0; n < dec_count; n++)
        {
            printf("%c", dec_digits[sizeof(dec_digits) - dec_count + n]+'0');
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

